# how to get group of data in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using an arraylist which contains
    arlist=[1,2,3,1,4,7,1,5,9]

now I'm looking for this kind of output 
    winningChance=[[1,2,3],[1,4,7],[1,5,9]] 
that means I have to separate into 3 group of elements and store that in another arraylist.
for that I have coded the following.

```
int size=arlist.size();
for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
winningChance.add(arlist.remove(i));
System.out.println(arlist);
System.out.println(winningChance);
```

for this code I'm getting the output as [[1,2,3]]. Can anybody suggest me to get the desired output.

Comment: Please explain a bit more for clarity .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to use the [modulo operator (`%`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), for example:

```java
final int elementsPerGroup = 3;

// your init list
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7, 1, 5, 9);

// the final list of lists
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

// logic
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    List<Integer> sublist;
    if (i % elementsPerGroup == 0) {
        sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listOfLists.add(sublist);
    } else {
        sublist = listOfLists.get(listOfLists.size() - 1);
    }
    sublist.add(list.get(i));
}
```

The final list of lists then equals `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method:

`List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

Change you logic  and Use [subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.)

ex: `list.subList(from, to).clear();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<T> T List<List<T>> group(final List<T> list, final int batchSize) {
    List<List<T>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int start = 0; start < list.size(); start += batchSize) {
        groups.add(list.subList(start, Math.min(start + batchSize, list.size()));
    }
    return groups;
}
```